# Deriving the information for Cramer-Rao Inequality

Tags: calculus, statistics, proof-explanation

For the part a), shouldn't differentiating both sides with respect to $\theta$ give $0 = 0$? I don't see how integration-differentiation interchange would work - there is no indication that $f(x)$ includes $\theta$ and even if it did, I still have no idea how to get to the result.

Here is the actual problem:

[image]

Comment: $X$ is a random variable with a $F_{\theta}(x)$ distribution, so it deppends on the parameter $\theta$

Comment: For example if $X\in N(\mu , 1)$, $\mu$ would be your $\theta$